# Find expression for PDF given range.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am trying to solve the following problem:
The random variable $Y$ has a negative exponential distribution with pdf as follows:

$ f(y) = λe^{−λy} , y > 0 $

Find an expression for the pdf of $Y$, assuming that $Y ≤ 200$.

I am aware that the integral of the pdf over its range (0-200 in this case) must sum to 1 but trying this method I end up with the following:

$ -e^{-200λ} + 1 = 1 $

Thus $ e^{-200λ} = 0 $

which quite plainly cannot be solved.
I am confused as to why my method isn't working, any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I'm presuming what you mean is that $f$ is the *density* function, and you want the conditional density given the event that $Y\le200$.

$$
\int_0^{200} \lambda e^{-\lambda y} \, dy = \left. -e^{-\lambda y} \vphantom{\frac\int\int} \, \right|_0^{200} = -e^{-200\lambda} - (-1) = 1-e^{-200\lambda}.
$$

So the conditional density is
$$
f(y) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{\lambda e^{-\lambda y}}{1-e^{-200\lambda}} & \text{if }0<y<200 \\[10pt] 0 & \text{otherwise.} \end{cases}
$$

The integral of that function from $0$ to $200$ is
$$
\int_0^{200} \frac{\lambda e^{-\lambda y}}{1-e^{-200\lambda}} \, dy = \frac 1 {1-e^{-200\lambda}} \int_0^{200} \lambda e^{-\lambda y} \, dy = 1.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your solution. I was mistakenly trying to solve for a value of $λ$ which evidently was incorrect, thank you for clearing this up for me.